# Getting Album Art From Music (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7

Creating an Application whereby I wouldn't mind getting album art from Music Files from the Zune App on WP7. 
Just wondering if this was possible.

This is My First Application on WP7 and my First User Space Application - since well.... Ever. 
Getting up to speed fairly well - Just this confuses me abit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there Natheniel,

Sorry, for my not being aware of how to do it using Zune or embedded API, but I've [found](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2480) the Amazon C# API samples, that would 100% help you getting album art from Amazon. Yes, I know, Amazon API is somewhat weird, but it actually works even in the cases the mp3 file itself does not have an album art at all. Try getting into it, and good luck